# Need to refactor an inline resource into a separate resource in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-openstack

In general, how can I refactor an inline resource and move it outside as a separate resource using a separate volume resource.

For example, is there a way to refactor a `block_device` and move it outside a `openstack_compute_instance_v2` as shown below?

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "instance_sakani_front_end_x" {
  ...
  block_device {
    uuid                  = ""
    volume_size           = 30
    boot_index            = 0
    destination_type      = "volume"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can pull the `block_device` out into a local map variable

```
   resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "instance_sakani_front_end_x" {
      ...
      block_device {
        uuid                  = ""
        volume_size           = 30
        boot_index            = 0
        destination_type      = "volume"
        delete_on_termination = true
      }
    }
```

Like so

```
locals {
    my_block_device {
        volume_size           = 30
        boot_index            = 0
        destination_type      = "volume"
        delete_on_termination = true
    }
}   

resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "instance_sakani_front_end_x" {
  ...
  block_device = "${local.my_block_device}"
}
```

Comment: What I need is to change the block_device into an openstack_compute_instance_v2 resource through refactoring without having to delete the volume and create it again.